# Como comparar strings digitadas pelo usuario com Strings já salvas em um .txt

Tags: java, txt

Estou trabalhando com manipulação de arquivos e não estou conseguindo comparar o que o usuário digita com a senha e login salvos no arquivo de cadastro da pessoa! Não consigo pegar uma posição especifica dentro do `.txt`

```
public class Validacao {
public static Aluno validarlogin() throws IOException {

    Aluno alu = new Aluno();
    Scanner logusuario = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite seu nome completo: ");
    alu.nome = logusuario.nextLine();
    String nomearq = alu.nome + ".txt";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nomearq));
    String linha = ";";

    while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null ){
        String[] vet = nomearq.split(";");
            if(alu.login.equals(vet[1]) && alu.senha.equals(vet[2])){
                System.out.println("Senha correta! ");

                alu.login(vet[2]);
                alu.senha(vet[3]);
            }

    }
    return alu;

}
```

**Com esse código eu obtenho esse erro:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Mas deveriam ter 12 Strings no meu `.txt`

Na hora de salvar o cadastro eu salvei separando com `;`.

E o `split()` era para passar os dados do `.txt` para um `ArrayList` não era?

Comment: Mostre o conteudo do seu txt. O erro informado é porque você está acessando um indice invalido do vetor `vet`.

Answer (score 0):

Este código:

```
String[] vet = nomearq.split(";");
```

não deveria ser assim?

```
String[] vet = linha.split(";");
```

pois como está declarado, a variavel `nomearq` é o nome do arquivo .txt, e não seu conteudo por linha

de qualquer forma, seria mais facil ver o conteudo do arquivo .txt, pelo o que está escrito, estou assumindo que o conteudo dele sejam varias linhas com login e senha no tipo:

```
algumacoisa;aluno;senha1;outras coisas
algumacoisa;aluno2;1234;outras coisas
algumacoisa;pass;user;outras coisas
algumacoisa;foo;1234;outras coisas
```

Mas acho que o principal erro é ter trocado `nomearq` por `linha` mesmo, teste isso e veja se funciona

Comment: Oi eu troquei nomearq por linha e deu o mesmo erro! o cadastro foi salvo no .txt desta forma: nome; login; senha; .... e eu preciso pegar o login e senha desta linha (posições 1 e 2) para comparar com o que foi digitado

Comment: por favor poste o conteudo do seu .txt para podermos avaliar melhor o motivo do erro

Comment: Conteudo do txt:   ary;ary;123456;789456;1;987654;av. Rio amazonas;09/05/1990;Sistemas de Informacao;5°;[TPIII, Redes I, Banco de Dados I];

Comment: no txt está tudo salvo em uma unica linha separado por ";".  existe uma forma melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: @Mayuri Você diz que tudo está em uma linha, tudo o que? Todas as informações? Tem somente uma linha no txt?

Eu acredito que seu erro, após mudar o `nomearq.split(";");` por `linha.split(";");` seja que as informações do objeto `Aluno` não estão preenchidas, `login` e `senha` no caso, tente setar um login e senha antes do while e então fazer a condição.